# UPDATE: A design update is coming!

Tags: discussion, design

### UPDATE

While I was converting the site to the new framework, as I said in this post, I also decided to refresh the design and layout. I'm aiming for a cleaner and more modern look which match the current Wordpress design & color scheme.

[image: Logo]

[image: header]

[image: 404]

Whether you want to keep the current design or want to see the new one in place, raise your voice!

Once I will have your opinion, the "new" version will be live as soon as possible.

---

These tweaks go along with recent updates that were made to Stack Overflow:

- We are moving the site's CSS to a newly refactored LESS system, so that it's easier for us to fix SE network CSS bugs globally and launch new features in the future.
- We are updating the graphics to SVG for retina support.
- We've fixed a LOT of obscure bugs that arose when new features were not thoroughly tested across the entire network.
- We will update the look to match the new design of Word**P**ress

**But more importantly, it will give you access to [the new profile](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2015/04/two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-on/)!**

This update should retro-actively fix most of the old design bugs. Once it goes live, we’ll update this post and if you see any new bugs, or old ones not yet fixed, please post an answer here to let us know!

Comment: Ah Yis, new profile finally! +1

Comment: Looking forward to it! I'm spending more and more time on this section and it would be nice to have a design similar to WordPress.com one.

Comment: Can we please get actual design/screenshots up as new thread? I almost missed it if it wasn't pointed out in chat, and votes are hard to interpret when mixed with earlier version of the thread.

Comment: I think having a separate thread for each new design concept would probably be the easiest, then whichever concept gets the most upvotes wins! Personally, I like the logo but I agree with Kraftner as far as the blue is kind of too close to the drupal exchange. Maybe we should go with a darker theme?

Comment: oh man, I'm going to miss the printing press... :) on the color topic, blue really isn't related to WordPress' color scheme, if anything it should be some anthracite with grey tones and white

Comment: We're going to get a lot of flack for the lower case p in WordPress

Comment: I should note, WordPress.org and WordPress.com aren't the same, WordPress.com is a hosted service, and questions about it are offtopic on this site, so you shouldn't consider its design to be the design of WordPress ( current WordPress.com UI is actually a Node.js + React app )

Comment: Wow, this new design looks sick!

Answer (score 19):

> We will update the look to match the new design of Wordpress

Newer model of printing press in header?.. :)

Seriously though thanks, and most looking forward to new profiles.

**On design refresh**

Ehm... Uhm... NOPE.

I get that it's a quick take on, but let's-abuse-WP-letters-into-logo/brand is horribly beaten track in our industry. Also capital P (WordPress). Also I am not sure what you are trying to match, since this doesn't remind me of anything in WP.

I don't know how this happens internally, but I do know some of the stacks have amazing designs and some... not so much. I know we are in a "not so much" group, but I'd say could we please at least keep the meh look that everyone is used to...

PS it was pointed out to me that this isn't very extensive feedback, another reason I'd like to see a separate thread for design proposition specifically.

Comment: Also with Drupal being one of the main contenders of WP I think this is way to close to http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Upvote for WordPress, camel cased.

Comment: capital_P_dangit();

Answer (score 9):

There are some major issues with the current redesign:

- We should swap the WP icon for a capital W, we can't use the standard WordPress logo as Stack Exchange is a for profit business, but we can approximate, I'm seeking clarification
- The word mark being used has a lower-case p, it's WordPress not Wordpress
- [The foundation trademark page](http://wordpressfoundation.org/trademark-policy/) suggests that if the design is too close to sites such as wordpress.org or wordpress.com and other community sites, enough to be mistaken as an official resource, then we can't use the trademarked logos. Otherwise we're okay to use them so long as we're not profiting from them

> We will grant permission to use the WordPress name and logo for projects that meet the following criteria:
>
> The primary purpose of your project is to promote the spread and improvement of the WordPress software.
>   Your project is non-commercial in nature (it can make money to cover its costs or contribute to non-profit entities, but it cannot be run as a for-profit project or business).
>   Your project neither promotes nor is associated with entities that currently fail to comply with the GPL license under which WordPress is distributed.

The lower-case p in WordPress will cause a fair amount of controversy and potential damage to our standing in the community. **If we can't spell the projects name how can we be trusted to provide useful information?**

I'd also like to suggest changing the 404 graphic. The Japanese WordPress community created a mascot called Wapuu, and having Wapuus on the error and 404 pages would be a big win and garner a lot of attention and news reporting from the community, especially if there was a Stack Exchange Wapuu!

Wapuu is a yellow creature wrapped around a ball of object with a WordPress logo on it:

[image]

Almost all existing Wapuus are GPL and should be good for use, coming in SVG and other formats, you can find the main archive here:

https://github.com/jawordpressorg/wapuu

It has the original Wapuu, and in the archive subfolder you'll find png and illustrator files for the other Wapuus

Comment: haha, yea, at least spell it right, trademark issues aren't to be overlooked too, so +1 for this. not so sure about the wapuus though, but that might just be a matter of personal taste.

Comment: Only for 404s and error pages ofcourse, no Wapuus on normal pages

Comment: so no wapuu as our new logo ;) I got that the first time around - actually :) still not my taste, but it wouldn't bother me too much either

Comment: We can update the "P" of wordpress to an uppercase for sure, but we can't use the real wordpress logo or something too close (I double checked with my company).

Answer (score 1):

I welcome the update. The old design was ok, but feels a little forced. I love classic typography, but something a little more modern feels appropriate now that a lot of WP sites don't really have that old style horizontal navigation any longer.

The new design looks more usable, but I would stay with the monochrome scheme personally.

Answer (score -1):

Special thanks to this wonderful community!

BTW what do u exactly mean by this?

> We will update the look to match the new design of Wordpress

Comment: We'll use a more modern look for the site and try to use the same color scheme as Wordpress (blues, white...)