# Fixing the new design

Tags: discussion, design

Many of you [had concerns](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/design-update-is-now-live) regarding the new design, so let's try to fix all these issues together and come with a better design for this community!

So first, let's list what we need to fix:

#### Color scheme

- The design reflects more wordpress.com than wordpress.org
- The site looks like se.drupal Q/A design

To avoid that we can:

- update the blue in the header to a dark grey (the one from wordpress.org)
- update other light blue grays to grays that match wordpress.org ones

#### Logo

- remove the W: We can't remove the mark, it's a convention and it's used throughout the network (mobile app, hot network questions, profile...)
- Update it to make it look a bit more like the wordpress.org one (color, shape)

#### Typography

Some people asked to update the typography but unfortunately we can't have a custom font on our network because it'd cause performances issues. All of our sites use default computer fonts (and if one don't, it'll be fixed ASAP).

#### New look

[image: Header]

For the active navigation item, I'm using the blue that wordpress.org uses for the "download" button in the header.

[image: Nav active]

#### Add the Japanese mascot Wapuu

We have a convention to use this kind of artwork in some special pages (404, error, captcha), so we can use it here. I don't think we can use it on the background as Wordpress lean toward a clean look.

404 page: regular Wapuu hanging on to wordpress

[image: 404]

Catpcha page: robot Wapuu (because captcha is here to trap robot)

[image: captcha]

Error page: Wapuu with burning wordpress ("something wrong is going on")

[image: error]

Comment: For what it's worth, I think the new design look great.

Comment: Nice, this is much better than the wordpress.com look, thanks for you help  on this!

Comment: This looks so much better. Whatever issues are left (logo .....) tnx for all your work to make this place nicer then the old design.

Comment: I'm going to be honest, I don't mind the logo and quite like the favicon. While we *aren't* WordPress we *do* deal with WordPress Development which *is* WordPress. I like the new design 100%.

Comment: The dark header/colour scheme is much better. It doesn't feel as clinical as the wordpress.com inspired design which to be honest has lost the charm of the original site we had.

Comment: wondering if there's a logic behind the left and right panel switch. if has user action, hints stay in right, if not, wapuu goes to the right?

Answer (score 18):

Thank you for listening to feedback and working with us to iterate on it.

My feedback on this version.

### Colors

Much better fit (or rather not-wordpress-com anymore, which was main issue :)

I think shade of header is a little *too* dark. WP org doesn't have toolbar on top like SE, it blends with it (needs divider line?). I think Tom had used a lighter shade in his tweaks.

### Typography

Default fonts are just fine. Overall it is improvement on previous design, especially after using it for a bit.

### Wapuus

**Great**. You even went further with it, the use of robot one is hilarious! :)

### Logo

Still not sold. It doesn't *have* to be nod to official WP logo. More so I'd prefer it *not* to be. The WP choice of abbreviation does not quite fit in first place. We are *not* WordPress project or even part of it.

The previous logo had just used W, though leafy background is tied in with previous design bit too much.

[image: old logo]

I would say that it should be one of:

- W (previous logo)
- WPSE (staple reference to site, though 4 letters is bulky)
- WD (for new Development name, though not in practical use so far).

The simple option would be to **keep the old W logo**. Maybe with minor tweaks (get rid of background or tweak it to tie in with new design).

Comment: +1 for logo, and indeed, it's a lighter shade I pulled from the .org design handbook, otherwise everything else is good, I know some people who'll be ecstatic over the Wapuu changes

Comment: If we can't agree on the logo, we'd remove the mark from the logo and keep the old favicon without the background.

Comment: @StéphaneMartin not quite following "remove the mark from the logo"? What from what? Do you mean keep the old W without leafy background bits? I'd be very fine with that. :)

Comment: why the leafs? it looks pretty but it seems its just a distraction.

Comment: @peteroak previous design had more elements like that, to be honest in most contexts they were barely notiecable in logo because of low contrast :) could easily lose them and just keep the W

Comment: @Rarst i like just the W, it has a strong connection with the WordPress brand, so i believe its easily understood. Maybe you can play around with it to add the SE?

Comment: About the **logo**. I could try my hand at it, but only if it's still a subject open to discussion / new proposals.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks a lot for the work on the new design with focus on speed and clarity. Thanks again for sharing and iterate with us.

#### Logo

I see no benefits with this new logo.
WPSE is not a WordPress project and I think, it is important to see that fast and clear. The community here is string and his name is WPSE. The common ground in my feeling is only the W in the name and that should be see at the top. Back to the old logo please.

#### Wapuu

Also here, I see no benefits. Yes, currently a lot of people in the community love it. But I think a lot of users of WPSE must ask about this Wapuu, what is that, which goal. They can't the background, the bridge to the WordCamp part.

#### Short

I mean, the WPSE-WordPress community should represent yourself, do not hide behind the WP Community and his pats. WPSE represent the community, is currently shure a string part of the community and I think, you should see it.

#### Design

Only a small hint from my view. It would be helpful, if the black header include the user information and search should be fixed, short access to his functions.